# How to only select inverted normals in 3DS max

Tags: 3dsmax, autodesk, 3ds

I'm trying to select only inverted normals from my mesh. 
say, for example, I have a branch of a tree, so, out of 100 branches 50% of the normals are inverted. So how do I select only those inverted normals by scripts rather than selecting them individually?

Answer (score 0):

In your case when the elements are separate and sort of solid, you should be able to send rays from the current viewpoint (say you'll set a regular grid limited by the tree bounding box for the rays), test for intersection and if the first face the ray hits faces away from the camera and the camera is not inside the geometry, there's a pretty big chance that face is inverted.